# Getting distinct count from two segments

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I'm trying to achieve:

The DB is postgres. We store users orders with a date of the purchase, and the `user_id`. I want to get the count of users who ordered this period AND last period (say it's a week, then it's people who ordered this week and last week).

I'm new to SQL and able to get the user count for this week, but that is where it stops.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(distinct(user_id))
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    shipment_state = 'shipped' AND
    delivery_date >= '2017-11-01' AND
    delivery_date <= '2017-11-10'
```

How do I now make it so that it gets the count of those who ordered in that period, but also f.ex the week before the 1st of November?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. `count(distinct user_id)` is the same as `count(distinct   (user_id))`

Comment: Updated, using postgres! @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little brute force, but assuming "this period" means November and "last period" means October, this would be a way of doing it:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    sum (case when delivery_date 
        between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-31' then 1 else 0 end) as last,
    sum (case when delivery_date 
        between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-30' then 1 else 0 end) as this
  FROM
    orders
  where
    shipment_state = 'shipped' and
    delivery_date >= '2017-10-01'
  group by user_id
)
select count (*)
from cte
where last > 0 and this > 0
```

One way you could do the weeks without hard-coding the values is to do something like this:

```
delivery_date between date_trunc ('week', current_date) and
   date_trunc ('week', current_date) + interval '6 days'
```

For the current week and the back it up by one week for the prior period:

```
delivery_date between date_trunc ('week', current_date) - interval '1 week' and
   date_trunc ('week', current_date) - interval '1 day'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN delivery_date >= '2017-11-01' AND delivery_date <= '2017-11-10'
                           THEN user_id
                      END),
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN delivery_date >= '2017-11-01' - INTERVAL '1 week' AND delivery_date < '2017-11-01'
                           THEN user_id
                      END)      
FROM orders o
WHERE shipment_state = 'shipped' AND
      delivery_date >= '2017-11-01' - INTERVAL '1 week' AND
      delivery_date <= '2017-11-10';
```

Comment: that leaves me with two counts. People who purchased last period and the current period. But I want the count of people who have both purchased in the current period and the last period. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes . . . Oh, I thought this is what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN delivery_date >= '2017-11-01' 
    AND delivery_date <= '2017-11-10'
                                   THEN user_id
                              END)
        FROM orders o
        WHERE user_id = (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
            FROM orders o    
            WHERE
                shipment_state = 'shipped' AND
                      delivery_date >= '2017-11-30' - INTERVAL '1 week' AND
                      delivery_date <= '2017-11-01')
  AND
   shipment_state = 'shipped' AND
   delivery_date >= '2017-11-01' - INTERVAL '1 week' AND
   delivery_date <= '2017-11-10';
```